# pandas syntax for more complex sql query

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, window-functions

I am looking for pandas syntax to do following aggregation to Pandas DataFrame. I cannot find an example how to accomplish following sql query in pandas.

```
#sum and divide
select
 click,
 ctr,
 SUM(click)/SUM(imp) as ctr
from mytable
group by website

#normalize each subgroup 
select
 imp,
 imp/SUM(imp) Over (partition website) as n_imp
from mytable
```

Comment: please provide a sample data set and desired data set

Comment: IMO the first SQL is erronous as `click` and `ctr` are not in the group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
#normalize each subgroup 
select
 imp,
 imp/SUM(imp) Over (partition website) as n_imp
from mytable
```

Pandas:

```
df[['website','imp']].assign(n_imp=df['imp']/df.groupby('website')['imp'].transform('sum'))
```